# Trying to upsize from Access tables to SQL Server linked tables. Code works fine with Access but gives a "ODBC call failed 3146" when connected to SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, vba, ms-access

```
Public Sub UpdateTermFeedbackAddlReqt(ByVal runid As Integer, ByVal BHTerm As String, ByVal username As String, ByVal currtime As Double)
    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
    
    DoCmd.SetWarnings False
    
    Set db = CurrentDb
    
    sql = "SELECT tbl_SCG_ExpectedTraffic.BHTerm, Sum(tbl_SCG_ExpectedTraffic.CurrSent2) AS SumOfCurrSent2, iif(Sum([CurrSent2]) = 0, 0, Sum([Accepted])/Sum([CurrSent2])) AS [Term Accept Rate], Sum(tbl_SCG_ExpectedTraffic.Accepted) AS SumOfAccepted, Sum(tbl_SCG_ExpectedTraffic.Rejected) AS SumOfRejected, Sum(tbl_SCG_ExpectedTraffic.Modified) AS SumOfModified, Sum(tbl_SCG_ExpectedTraffic.CurrCalledin) AS SumOfCalledin, Sum([ExpTotal])-Sum([CurrSent2]) AS [Need to Send]" & _
    " FROM tbl_SCG_ExpectedTraffic" & _
    " GROUP BY Date(), tbl_SCG_ExpectedTraffic.BHTerm, tbl_SCG_ExpectedTraffic.OptRunID" & _
    " HAVING (((tbl_SCG_ExpectedTraffic.OptRunID)=" & runid & ") And BHTerm= """ & BHTerm & """);"
    Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(sql, dbOpenDynaset, dbSeeChanges)
    DoCmd.RunSQL ("Update tbl_SCG_TerminalFeedback set [CurrentSend2] = " & rs![SumOfCurrSent2] & ", [Term Accept Rate] =" & rs![Term Accept Rate] & ", Accepted= " & rs![SumOfAccepted] & ", Rejected = " & rs![SumOfRejected] & ", Modified =" & rs![SumOfModified] & ", Calledin = " & rs![SumOfCalledin] & ", AddlReqst =" & rs![Need To Send] & _
    ",[Last Update User] =""" & username & """, [Last Update Time]= " & currtime & " , HrDiff = iif( isnull(DLookup(""SubmissionDT"", ""tbl_SCG_OptRunSummary"", ""OptRunID = " & runid & """)), 0, Round((" & currtime & " - DLookup(""SubmissionDT"", ""tbl_SCG_OptRunSummary"", ""OptRunID =" & runid & """)) * 24, 1))" & _
    " where OptRunID = " & runid & " And Term = """ & BHTerm & """")
    
    DoCmd.SetWarnings True
    
    rs.Close
    db.Close
    
End Sub
```

Comment: [How to debug dynamic SQL in VBA](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1099570/3820271)

Comment: This VBA worked when tables were in Access? Try # delimiter for date/time field parameters: `=#" & currtime & "#,`

Comment: In SQL Server [`HAVING`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-having-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) is for aggregate conditions, try replacing it with `WHERE`. If this does not help, follow @Andre 's suggestion.